# jQuery menu which is switching a blocks below + links to active blocks

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, toggle

So I made a simple menu which is switching a blocks below, thats ok - here is my [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coffeecupdrummer/cg9Rx/).
But I need to be able to link to those blocks from outside.

It's hard to describe with words, so I have an example - 
[*You will find a menu there and you will be on a "Fetures" menu item*](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/features) and here is [*link on a second menu item - "Demo"*](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/demos).

Here is my code:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="linkOne" href="#/first">First</a></li>
        <li><a id="linkTwo" href="#/second">Second</a></li>
        <li><a id="linkThree" href="#/third">Third</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p id="first">First Paragraph</p>
    <p id="second">Second Paragraph</p>
    <p id="third">Third Paragraph</p>
```

and js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#linkOne').click(function(){
        $('#first').show();
        $('#second').hide();
        $('#third').hide();
    });
    $('#linkTwo').click(function(){
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').show();
        $('#third').hide();
    });
    $('#linkThree').click(function(){
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#second').hide();
        $('#third').show();
    });
});
```

I didnt find any tutorials or good examples on that, so if you know one please throw me a line.

Comment: I can't figure out what the question is.

Comment: I gave two links to [dev7studios.com](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/features). There is a jQuery menu that is showing or hiding a section below + you can link to exact menu item like so - [support menu item](http://dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/#/support) - How did they made it possible to link on exact menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets the hash (#) and looks for the div with the ID that matches the hash.

```
if(window.location.hash){
    var whichDiv = window.location.hash;
    $(whichDiv).show();
}
```

You need to edit these so that the hash matches the ID of the paragraph (removed the `/`):

```
<li><a id="linkOne" href="#first">First</a></li>
<li><a id="linkTwo" href="#second">Second</a></li>
<li><a id="linkThree" href="#third">Third</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advocate for using the click instead of the show, but same idea:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#linkOne').click(function(){
    $('#first').show();
    $('#second').hide();
    $('#third').hide();
});
$('#linkTwo').click(function(){
    $('#first').hide();
    $('#second').show();
    $('#third').hide();
});
    $('#linkThree').click(function(){
    $('#first').hide();
    $('#second').hide();
    $('#third').show();
});

if(location.hash) $(location.hash).click();
});
```